# Cambio un valor de un diccionario y se me cambian todos los valores

Tags: python, lista, variables, diccionarios

tengo un problema y es este:
estoy creando una lista de 10 elementos con diccionarios adentro, el problema es que cuando le doy el valor a un elemento de la lista se me cambian todos los valores de la lista

```
   def declararLisstas(lista,tamano, tipo):
           for i in range(tamano):
               lista.append(tipo)

   tipo = dict()
   ejemplo = list()
   declararLisstas(ejemplo,10, tipo)
   ejemplo[0]['valor'] = 1
```

para este caso solo quiero que me cambie el valor [0] de la lista, pero me imprime esto:

```
    [{'valor': 1},
     {'valor': 1},
     {'valor': 1},
     {'valor': 1},
     {'valor': 1},
     {'valor': 1},
     {'valor': 1},
     {'valor': 1},
     {'valor': 1},
     {'valor': 1}]
```

Es decir me cambia todos los elementos de la lista.

Alguien sabe como puedo solucionarlo?

Answer (score 0):

Debes copiar el diccionario,lo que estas haciendo es agregar a la lista el mismo elemento, literalmente el mismo, es decir este elemento ocupa un espacio en memoria, y copias el mismo elemento con la misma dirección en memoria, así que si editas el primero, como el resto están apuntando a la misma dirección todos cambiaran, para eso usas `.copy()` que realiza una copia exacta pero otro espacio de la memoria

```
def declararLisstas(lista,tamano, tipo):
  for i in range(tamano):
    lista.append(tipo.copy())
```

Comment: ya pude solucionar el error, Gracias!!

Answer (score 0):

En vez de pasar la la función un objeto/instancia de la clase `dict` (`dict()`) pasa le la propia clase (AKA tipo). Todos los items de tu lista son el mismo diccionario, por lo que modificar un item los modifica todos ya que todos los items son referencias al mismo objeto en memoria:

```
def inicializar_lista(lista, tamaño, tipo):
       for _ in range(tamaño):
           lista.append(tipo())

tipo = dict
ejemplo = list()
inicializar_lista(ejemplo, 10, tipo)
ejemplo[0]['valor'] = 1
```

> ```
> >>> ejemplo
> [{'valor': 1}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}]
> ```

Comment: entendí la solución, Gracias!!